# Arc and vector question

Tags: geometry

The point $B$ is on arc $AC = 90$, with center $O$.

$AB/BC= \frac 12$

Express vector $\overrightarrow {OC}$ with vectors $\overrightarrow {OA}$ and $\overrightarrow {OB}$

Comment: Is $AB/BC= \frac 12$ in angular measure or straight line distances?.  Pesumably $AC=90$ means $90^\circ$, correct?

Comment: AB/BC=1/2 in arc length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Let $O$ be the origin, $A$ be $(1,0)$, $C$ be $(0,1)$.  Where is $B$?  Then write $\vec{OC}=a\vec{OA}+b\vec{OB}$ and you have two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: This problem would be more interesting had $AB$ etc been straight line distances.